# Using LIMIT in sparql update?

Tags: sparql, jena

I need to modify triples in a very large repository, so to avoid memory issues I want to do a basic sparql update but split it up into chunks.

```
DELETE { ?s predi:cate ?o }
INSERT { ?s predi:cate <http://whatever> }
WHERE { ?s predi:cate ?context} LIMIT 100
```

is what I would like to do, but I get a sparql syntax error with the limit so I'm assuming that wont work.

Is a sub query the only way? I was able to get a little further by doing something like:

```
DELETE { ?s predi:cate ?o }
INSERT { ?s predi:cate <http://whatever> }
WHERE { SELECT ?s ?o { ?s predi:cate ?o } LIMIT 100}
```

The update seems to work in this case, but the weird thing is that if the limit is 100 or 100000 the query still takes the same amount of time to execute, so it doesn't seem very effecient. Thoughts?

edit: Here is the full query.

```
DELETE {
    GRAPH ?g {
        ?uri MY:URI ?context
    }
}

INSERT {
    GRAPH ?g {
        ?uri  MY:URI ?context2
    }
}

WHERE {
    GRAPH ?g {
        SELECT ?uri ?context ?context2 {
            ?uri MY:URI  ?context . 
            BIND(URI(REPLACE(STR(?context),"olddomain","newdomain") AS ?context2) } LIMIT 100
    }
}
```

So far it looks like its deleting and inserting every record, but its only replacing 100. Is there a way to reorder this so that it only deletes/inserts what has changed? Sorry I'm somewhat new to sparql

Comment: In the first example, DELETE { ?s predi:cate ?o } isn't going to do anything - ?o is unbound.  Are these the actual updates you're trying?  If now, maybe their pattern is inducing some other effect.

Comment: It actually seems like its deleting all the matches and reinserting them, please read my edit in the original post. I posted the full query so that may shed some more light on things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the rewritten original query we have:

```
WHERE {
    GRAPH ?g {
        SELECT ?uri ?context ?context2 {
            ?uri MY:URI  ?context . 
            BIND(URI(REPLACE(STR(?context),"olddomain","newdomain") AS ?context2)
        } LIMIT 100
    }
}
```

so the LIMIT is inside the GRAPH ?g, limiting it to 100 for each GRAPH ?g.

Put the

```
   WHERE
    { SELECT ?uri ?context ?context2 {
          GRAPH ?g {
            ?uri MY:URI  ?context . 
            BIND(URI(REPLACE(STR(?context),"olddomain","newdomain") AS ?context2)
          }
       } LIMIT 100
    }
```

if that is not the core issue, please provide a complete, minimal, working example.

Comment: You got me 95% of the way there! I just had to add a ?g to the SELECT in your WHERE clause, making it SELECT ?g ?uri ?context ?context2 and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you see may we'll be dependent on the underlying SPARQL engine.  The fact that the limited query takes the same amount of time as the unlimited query implies that the bottleneck is the `WHERE` clause of your query.  Depending on how your SPARQL engine is implemented adding `LIMIT` doesn't necessarily make evaluating the query portion any faster.

You can test this out by running just the `WHERE` portion of your update as a query with and without the `LIMIT` to see if the execution time is roughly the same.  If it is then there may be nothing you can do to improve performance other than talk to your vendor.

Btw for performance related questions like this it is helpful to know details of your software and hardware environment otherwise you'll only get general speculative answers like mine.

Comment: Its jena arq and tdb so I imagine that the limit should function properly. I think the real problem here is that my query is deleting and inserting all the records over, event though its only changing 100 (see my edit above). So is there a way in the sparql update spec to redorder this, so i am only saving what changed?